# Find out all the parameters of a REST DLL

Tags: rest

I have been provided with a WebService with a REST Interface, implemented as a DLL.The documentation is really poor, and does not detail all the possible parameters.

Is there any way to get all the parameters that the DLL can accept without disassembling the DLL(something like a man function)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't.

Of course you can list all functions with [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) and hope that you will find something like `man` function. But most probably you should use trial and error method here. Call functions and examine what they do.

PS: if there's a way to obtain documentation or source code, it will be the most correct way.

Comment: I'll get in touch with the devs then.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "very unlikely". It really depends on how those services were implemented. If they really are REST, they should comply with the HATEOAS principle, so you should theoretically be able to navigate all the services just by following links provided by the responses. If this is true, all you need to know is the entry point of the services. 
Or, there could be a WADL describing the service 'topology' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language).
On the other hand, if the services were not implemented this way (I won't say 'properly', but..), I am afraid you don't have many options apart from diving into the implementation.